# Why are the nested objects in my parent object null when posting to my MVC 4 Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, asp.net-mvc-controller

Let's say I have a complex model which contains a custom class:

```
    public class Car
{
    public Car() {}
    public Engine engine { get; set } // nested object
    public int FuelRemaining {get; set;}
    public int VehicleStatus {get; set;}
}
```

And an MVC 4 Controller that looks something like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult ShowVehicleDetails(Car currentVehicle)
    {
        return PartialView(currentVehicle);
    }
```

If I pass an instance of this class to the controller using an ajax post, and then try to return a view, partial view, or even just peek into the object, all of the values of *engine* are *null*, but everything else is fine.

**Here in example of the JSON that I see showing up in the form data of the request header for the POST:**

```
{"engine":{"engineVIN":258736,"engineKM":160015,"EngineDesc":"EcoTech V8"},"FuelRemaining":90,"VehicleStatus":1}
```

**Note:** Values for *FuelRemaining*, and *VehicleStatus* are showing up just fine in the controller and in the resulting view.

Can someone explain to me why this is the case, and how best to work around this?

I did come across [this blog article](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2010/02.aspx) from the asp.net team, but it is dated 2010 and I haven't been able to find any more recent information.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework by chance?

Comment: Yes, this is using EF 5.

Comment: Odds are you have lazy loading on and it doesn't populate the object.  Try using `.Include(c => c.Engine)`.  This will force it to load the object and you shouldn't end up with a null object.

Comment: What values are you sending in the ajax post?

Comment: Show us your jquery ajax code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A closer look at a sample I found online of passing complex objects to a controller clearly indicated that I was neglecting to set the *contentType* when making the ajax call.

Specifically, a working call should look like this:

```
        var jsonData = { "StartDate": selectedDate, "EndDate": selectedDate };

    $.ajax(
            {
                url: '@Url.Action("GetMyConcertTickets", "Main")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    populateMyConcertTicketsOnGrid(data);
                }
            });
```

If you don't tell the controller that you are passing *"application/json"*, then I think it will expect *"text/html"*.

Comment: Care to expand on that?  How would one tell the controller the content type?  Your answer is incomplete for those of us who don't know the context, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The objects from model binding can only be hydrated with the values that are posted.  Hence if there are no values in your post corresponding to the asscoiated `Engine` object than none of its properties will be populated.

The default model binding will create a new instance of the object or objects it sees in the action method's parameter list.  If you would like the model binding to pull an existing object, say from the database, than you will need a custom model binder.

Comment: The post is definitely passing along a complete instance of the class - I have verified this by manually populating the object. Could this maybe be an issue with JSON?

Comment: Ah ok.  By a complete instance of the class do you mean `Car`?  Does it have values for the `Engine` instance as well?

Comment: Yes it does. I added an example of the JSON string that I am seeing get passed off to the controller via HTTP POST.

Comment: @Ray but is that what you are sending back to the server?  Fiddler can help diagnose this

Comment: That is what is showing up in the payload on the network traffic when I check in the chrome web developer tool.

Comment: Model binding is very explicit about naming.  For associated objects to be hydrated the value keys should be separated by dots.  So the key should look like `Engine.VIN`.

Comment: Did that help at all?